# Ajax callback to create paragraphs on form

Tags: forms, ajax, files

I'm trying to create a way that an end user can upload a csv into a node form and it automatically extracts the content and then creates paragraphs in the form.

[image: Form example]

I have created a custom managed file class that I'm modifying the uploadAjaxCallback function and it extracts the csv contents and I can set some html under the file field using and ajaxCommand but I want to replace or append paragraphs to the existing field.

```
  public static function uploadAjaxCallback(&$form, FormStateInterface &$form_state, Request $request) {
    // load the CSV document from a file path
    $absolute_path = \Drupal::service('file_system')->realpath('private://catalogue_import/orders.csv');
    $encoder = new CsvEncoder();
    $data = $encoder->decode(file_get_contents($absolute_path), 'csv');

    // Return the paragraph element.
    $content = '<table><thead><th>UID</th><th>Email</th></thead><tbody>';
    foreach ($data as $row){
      $content .= '<tr><td>' . $row['Uid'] . '</td><td>'. $row['Email'] .'</td></tr>';
    }
    $content .= '</tbody></table>';
    $Selector = '.harps-file'; /* See: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp */
    $response = parent::uploadAjaxCallback($form, $form_state, $request);
    $response->addCommand(new HtmlCommand($Selector,$content));

    return $response;

  }
```

If I return the paragraph field in the response then it replaces the file upload.

Is what I'm trying to do even achievable ?

Thanks

Comment: As I understand, you using a hook_form_alter to add Ajax callback. If yes, then You should create a custom field widget, for the Paragraph Reference field type and implement Ajax without alters.

Comment: I'll give that a go but I still think I'll have the same issues. The ajaxCallback I'm using is in the file_managed field type. When I upload a file this triggers the ajaxCallback